# HTML - Help me understand how this script works

Tags: html, css

Total novice at HTML here. I'm merely trying to figure out how to create drop down buttons for a small project. This is the code for a drop down button that I found on w3.

I want to have more than one drop down button. If I copy the `<div class="dropdown">`, clicking on either button only triggers the first drop down button.

What specifically is triggering this, and what is the proper way to create more than 1 button?

```js
    /* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    .show {display:block;}
    </style>
    </head>
```

```html
    <h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code, is this what you need?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
     }

    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }

   .dropdown {
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
   }

  .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

 .dropdown-content a {
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 }

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

  <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 2</a>
    <a href="#about">About 2</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");

  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];

    if (openDropdown.id !== id && openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
     }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question

> If I copy the , clicking on either button only triggers the first drop down button.What specifically is triggering this

i guess you are copying the entire div, like so?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will effectively **duplicate your id**  , so the myFunction()'s snippet of code shown below

```
 document.getElementById("myDropdown")
```

will **select the first** #myDropdown it encounters and do its magic of toggling classes and hence you feel it triggers only the first drop down.

> what is the proper way to create more than 1 button?

Actually there are many ways , but since you are a begginer i reckon i can safely say that copy pasting is fine :) as long as you dont repeat the ids.

But if you are actually looking for a fix of the code, i guess the answer by @Lahiru should cover you !

Cheers and happy learning